# how to get the right values ​in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the following columns in a single array:

```
table_1.id, table_2.value

['table_1.id' = > 1, 'table_2.value' = 'text']
['table_1.id' = > 2, 'table_2.value' = 'text']
```

But I get a different array from each table.

```
['table_1.id' = > 1]
['table_2.value' = 'text']

['table_1.id' = > 2]
['table_2.value' = 'text']
```

my request:

```
DB::table('info')
            ->join('meta_tag', function ($join) {
                $join->on('auto_info.brand', '=', 'meta_tag.id')->orON('info.year', '=', 'meta_tag.id')
                    ->where('info.user', '=', Auth::id())
                    ->select('info.user_id', 'meta_tag.value');
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

just move the select outside your 'join':

```
DB::table('info')
            ->join('meta_tag', function ($join) {
                $join->on('auto_info.brand', '=', 'meta_tag.id')->orON('info.year', '=', 'meta_tag.id')
                    ->where('info.user', '=', Auth::id());
              
            })->select('info.user_id', 'meta_tag.value')
            ->get();
```

Comment: He scatters anyway.
`
need to:
`
@foreach ($user as $val)
{{ $val->auto_info.brand}} 
{{ $val-> info.year}}
{{ $val-> info.user}}
@endforeach
`